# How much current does this read?

Tags: multimeter

How much current is flowing here?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left most position is 0 for currents, the right most if the range value,

So for the 500mA range you would be looking at the lower black range and times any reading by 10,

So in this case, you would be reading 120mA

Answer (score -1):

Or a little bit more accurate:
upper black scale shows 60
60mA x 2 = 120 mA

Comment: Would have be better if the OP aligned the camera so that the photograph of the needle is coincident with the reflected image of the needle.

Comment: Yes off course!!!